# Query to find the running sum of a column(qty) based on type(if 'a' add else subtract)

Tags: ms-access

I have table with data as follows:

```
Store     ItemNo     Type   Billno   Qty
London      1          A      1      10
London      1          A      2       5
London      1          S      1       7
London      1          A      3       5
London      1          S      2       7
London      2          A      1      19
London      2          S      2       5
London      2          A      3      11
Paris       1          A      1      15
Paris       1          S      2       8
Paris       1          A      3       9
Paris       2          A      1      10
Paris       2          S      2       5
```

Now i want to calculate **TotalQty**, such that **totalqty** of qty of an **itemno** under particular **store** is calculated based on **type**. i.e. if type is **A**, qty should be added to total and if it is **S** , subtracted from total as shown below. In the example below for **store** *london* ,**itemno** 1 **row 3** is the last entry,so the **totalQty** gives the current quantity availble for that item in that particular store.

```
Store     ItemNo     Type   BillNo  Qty   TotalQty
London      1          A       1     10      10
London      1          A       2      5      15
London      1          S       1      7       8
London      1          A       3      5      13
London      1          S       2      7       6
London      2          A       1     19      19
London      2          A       2      5      24
London      2          S       3     11      13
Paris       1          A       1     15      15
Paris       1          S       2      8       7
Paris       1          A       3      9      16
Paris       2          A       1     10      10
Paris       2          S       2      5       5
```

Comment: -1 Your table violates first normal form (1NF) i.e. there is nothing from the data (other than the display) to tell us that {London, 1, A, 10} is immediately prior to {London, 1, A, 5}.

Comment: From you edit I infer your key is (Store, ItemNo, BillNo). In you example table you have {London, 2, A, 1, 8} but in your results this changes to {London, 2, A, 1, 19} -- is this a typo?

Comment: ...actually all the data for London 2 changes between posted table and posted results.

Comment: "In the example below for London 1 row 3 is the last entry" -- that's not how I see it. For London 1 the last row is BillNo=2 Type=S; the pattern seems to be "if (Store, ItemNo, Billno) is duplicated then 'swap' the Type=s row with the ItemNo row but there isn't enough data to make this a safe guess. Please clearly explain why for London 1 the rows (BillNo, Type) are in the sequence (1, A), (2, A), (1, S), (3, A), (2, S).

Comment: (1, A), (2, A), (1, S), (3, A), (2, S)
The sequence is like this because it is ordered by date. I have not shown date column in data table. Actually records with type A are from different table and s from different table. The above shown Data Table is the output of another query
To explain you in detail
There are 5 tables like itemissue, itemReturn, ItemPurchasereturn, Receipts, Storemaster. Assume it to be centralized database where data come from different stores for same itemno. Billno is unique to store and type of transaction. I have shown type A,S to identify data from 5 different tables

Comment: "I have not shown date column in data table" -- again, then your table _as posted_ violates 1NF (i.e. no key). I suggest you edit your question to add the date column to both the table and expected results.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand you right, you need to use the IIf statement:

```
SELECT Store, ItemNo, SUM(IIF(Type = 'A', Qty, 0 - Qty)) AS TotalQty
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Store, ItemNo
```

should produce the following (untested):

```
Store    ItemNo    TotalQty
London     1          8
London     2         13
Paris      1         16
Paris      2          5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is it (I was confused but then spotted your data is inconsistent between table and results):

```
SELECT S1.Store, S1.ItemNo, S1.Type, S1.Billno, S1.Qty, 
       (
        SELECT SUM(SWITCH(
                          S2.Type = 'A', S2.Qty, 
                          S2.Type = 'S', 0 - S2.Qty, 
                          TRUE, NULL
                          ))
          FROM StoreStuff AS S2
         WHERE S2.Store = S1.Store
               AND S2.ItemNo = S1.ItemNo
               AND S2.Billno <= S1.Billno
       ) AS TotalQty
  FROM StoreStuff AS S1
 ORDER
    BY S1.Store, S1.ItemNo, S1.Billno;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your query gives me exactly what i want.but there was one problem because i had not properly depicted data in table.I have updated my table in question.Now in the data table you can see that combination of Store, Itemno, Billno, Type makes the row unique.We can have same billno in two differnt 'Type' under same store and Itemno.Pls help me with this also.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: He he: the answer that doesn't give you what you need has more upvotes :) How about marking mine as an answer. I've added a comment to your question for your next problem because I do't quite follow the sequence.